# Ruby - refactoring to handle different types of errors

Tags: ruby, refactoring

I have an object that serves as a parent object to several others.  It has a method similar to this:

```
class Parent
  def commit
    begin
    ...
    rescue => e
    ...
    end
  end
end

class ChildA < Parent
end

class ChildB < Parent
end
```

However, `ChildA` has to behave in a unique way when `commit` throws a specific type of error, `UniqueError`.  I could overwrite the whole `commit` file for that function, but that feels awkward. It sets me up for problems if I need to change the body in the `begin` section, since I now would need to change it in two places.

What's the cleanest way to refactor this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't be swallowing *all* types of exceptions with a `rescue => e`. That line of code should almost never exist. Your exception handler should only capture the types of exceptions it can meaningfully recover from.

Change your Parent so that it doesn't swallow all exceptions, and then catch them in your Child class:

```
class Parent

  def commit
    # ...
  end 

end

class Child < Parent
  def commit
    begin
      super
    rescue UniqueError => e
      # ...
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: What if there is one known exception that I need to rescue from in a consistent way in the Parent class, e.g. rescuing from `ActiveRecord::ResourceNotFound`?  Can you have a parent that rescues from just one error, and somehow just extend that in the Child class?